# Is it enough to use mysqli in PHP to prevent SQL injections?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

For example I use

```
$building_name = $_POST['BuildingName'];
$metering_type = $_POST['MeteringType'];
$query = "INSERT INTO buildings (BuildingName, MeteringType)
                       VALUES ('$building_name', '$metering_type')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $query))
{
    echo json_encode(Array("success"=>true));
}
```

And I believe that this prevents me from SQL injections. Am I safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that doesn't protect you in the slightest.

You need to use [MySQLi's parameterized queries via `prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).